# How to read excel File from ASHX page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, filehandler

Hi i have uploaded file to one amazon s3 server,how can i read excel file and want to send excel data to database.
my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var obj = null;
         $(function () {
             $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                 replaceFileInput: false,
                 formData: function (form) {
                     return [{ name: "name1", value: "value1" }, { name: "name2", value: "value2"}];
             $('#btnGo').click(function () {
                 obj.submit();
             });
         });
     </script>
```

And my ashx page, where i need to read excel data

```
public class AjaxFileHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var file = context.Request.Files[0];
            string fileName=fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + file.FileName;
            Stream streamContentFile = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;

            var iFileSize = context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
            byte[] data = new byte[iFileSize];
            int bytes_read = 0;
            while (bytes_read < iFileSize)
            {
                int bytes_read_this_iteration = streamContentFile.Read(data, bytes_read, iFileSize - bytes_read);
            streamContentFile.Close();
            streamContentFile.Dispose();
            CommonBLL.UploadTemporaryFilesToS3Bucket(fileName, data);
//Here i need to read excel code can you provide how to do that pleas
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two things:

- a **Driver** that allows code to read Excel content
- **access** to this file
- a **query** over excel data

In this sample:

- I use [ACE (Microsoft Access Database Engine)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) driver, that must be installed on the server
- the file is in `App_Data` folder (in your case the file should be rached CommonBLL library, i suppose)
- the query is an `UPDATE` query; you can replace with a `SELECT` or `INSERT` query, using common DB SNippets.

  ```
  string fileName= Server.MapPath( "~/App_Data/MyFile.xls");
  string sheetName= "Sheet1";
  string connString = string.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"
        , fileName);
  string command = string.Format("UPDATE [{0}${1}:{1}] SET F1='{2}'", sheetName,cellName, cellValue);

     using (OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
      {
          oledbConn.Open();
          using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, oledbConn))
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          oledbConn.Close();
      }
  ```

Comment: I am getting error as "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

Comment: @user1527989 The Application needs write authorization to that file. Googling you can find many solutions. Anyway, if AmanzonSrBucket has too many permissions restrictions, you can edit the file in Application\App_Data folder an then send it to Amazon

Answer (score 0):

I would use open source libraries for excel, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (xslx) or [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) (xls). They are very easy to use, and I am using EPPlus for numerous excel imports / exports and it's working great. These libraries have no external dependancies, and you can use it on server side.